# Custom Attribute calculated from another one

Tags: azure, dynamic, hash, attributes

My users in azure have a field containing thair userID, now i want to do a federation but dont want to pass the userID to the external SaaS, but want to use the md5(userID) so i need a new attribute that is calculated on the fly hashing the userID associated to the user to use that in the federation. How could i do that easily, an operational/dynamic attribute?

i would like to calculate that attribute directly on Azure and not have to propagate it from the OnPrem IAM authoritathive system that provision the users via the local AD and AD connet to Azure.

Comment: Note that, depending on the details of userID, md5(userID) may be quite easy to reverse.

Answer (score 0):

An Azure Function would probably be the easiest way of handling this. I do not think that Azure AD/Entra ID has any such native capability but I would love to be proven wrong on this.

If going the Azure Function route PowerShell and Graph API would likely be the best documented and supported path.